# How to count number of times a variable exceeded its threshold . Ignore consecutive events

Tags: r, dplyr

I have to find out how much time a variable exceeded its threshold for every 10 minutes. In the below The variable Threshold Event denotes 0 or 1 . 1 represents it exceeded its threshold while 0 is normal.

Variable is car speed so if its exceeded a limit( say 35 kmph) it will continue to stay above that limit for sometime before the speed comes down to normal again (0). so I need to exclude such consecutive events & only count it as once everytime it exceeds that limit.

Can someone please help..I tried with `dplyr` to filter & put a condition around the threshold but I am not able to succeed..

Sample Data

```
         Timestamp                  Speed      Threshold

1  2014-04-03 09:23:57            30.07929         0
2  2014-04-03 09:23:55            35.63192         1
3  2014-04-03 09:23:59            34.92283         0
    .                             .
    .                             . 
4  2014-04-03 09:33:01            37.30859         1
5  2014-04-03 09:33:02            38.58576         1
6  2014-04-03 09:33:03            39.51970         1
7  2014-04-03 09:33:04            38.02424         1
8  2014-04-03 09:33:05            33.12697         0
9  2014-04-03 09:33:39            30.21950         0
10 2014-04-03 09:33:40            31.27000         0
11 2014-04-03 09:33:41            32.00667         1
12 2014-04-03 09:33:42            32.94374         1
13 2014-04-03 09:33:43            33.25141         1
14 2014-04-03 09:33:44            32.76980         1
15 2014-04-03 09:33:45            30.11010         0
16 2014-04-03 09:33:56            31.63525         0
17 2014-04-03 09:33:57            34.61222         0
18 2014-04-03 09:33:58            37.52020         1
19 2014-04-03 09:33:59            40.48424         1
20 2014-04-03 09:34:00            43.43828         0
```

.............................................................

Output should look like

```
CAR ID             Time (Sec)               Count
XXXX                2014-04-03 09:23:00         1
xxxx                2014-04-03 09:33:00         3
.                         .                     .
.                         .                     .
```

Comment: Please provide sample of the data with `dput()` function. Expected output is also unclear.

Comment: What does "6" mean in the output. Also, please provide example input and an expected for that example input.

Comment: I changed the output now to make it clear & more inline to above sample data.. however to answer your question, in earlier output 6 means number of times threshold exceeded in the 10 minute window (in other words, number of times consecutive ones appeared). Please let me know if its not clear.

Comment: In your sample data, there is no variable "car id". Is the data set  meant for one single car id?

Comment: No its for multiple cars but for simplicity I deleted it. I thought we can do a groupby car ID later..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `CAR_ID` and `cut` the `Timestamp` column into groups of every "10 minutes" and calculate how many times the value exceeds the `Threshold` separately (excluding consecutive enteries) using `rle`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(CAR_ID, group = cut(Timestamp, breaks = "10 mins")) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(with(rle(Threshold), values == 1)))
```

Make sure that `Timestamp` column is of `datetime` or `POSIXct` class and not string.

Comment: Truly genius  this worked. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group it by every 10 minutes starting from 3rd minute you can do it like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(Timestamp = str_sub(ymd_hms(Timestamp) - minutes(3), 1, 15)) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(Treshhold)) %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = str_c(Timestamp, '3'))
```

Comment: Chabros I added a sample data.. please take a look at it

Comment: Dear Pawel Chabros, I am looking for count of such consecutive 1's appeared for every 10 minutes..not the sum. please advise.